# Dynamically merge Akka streams

Tags: scala, merge, stream, akka, akka-stream

I’m trying to use Akka streams to build a pub sub bus in the following way:

Publisher adds a source stream for the topic and subscribers specify a topic and get everything for that topic. However topic may be published by multiple Publishers, and both publisher and subscribers can join at any point.

What I had in mind is to combine all sources and then return the filtered source to a subscriber.

However as publishers may join at any point sources may be added after a subscription has been made and the subscriber needs to get data from it like any other published data for the topic.

Is there a way to manage the merging of streams to a source dynamically such that the following will hold:

```
publish(topic: String, messages: Source[T])
subscribe(topic: String): Source[T]
```

Such that regardless of when a publisher is added a subscriber to a topic will get all messages published to any source related to the topic after the subscription is made.

Happy to hear about alternative approaches too.

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this Akka doc re: building a [`dynamic pub-sub service`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#combining-dynamic-operators-to-build-a-simple-publish-subscribe-service) using [`MergeHub`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/MergeHub$.html) and [`BroadcastHub`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/BroadcastHub$.html).

Here's sample code for using a [`MergeHub`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#using-the-mergehub) and a [`BroadcastHub`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#using-the-broadcasthub) as dynamic fan-in and fan-out junctions, respectively.

The idea is to connect a `MergeHub` with a `BroadcastHub` to form a pub-sub channel in the form of a Flow via [`Flow.fromSinkAndSource`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Flow/fromSinkAndSource.html):

```
val (bfSink, bfSource) = MergeHub.source[String](perProducerBufferSize).
  toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[String](bufferSize))(Keep.both).
  run

val busFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(bfSink, bfSource)
```

Note that `Keep.both` in the above snippet produces a Tuple of materialized values `(Sink[T, NotUsed], Source[T, NotUsed])` from `MergeHub.source[T]` and `BroadcastHub.sink[T]` which have the following method signatures:

```
object MergeHub {
  def source[T](perProducerBufferSize: Int): Source[T, Sink[T, NotUsed]] = // ...
  // ...
}

object BroadcastHub {
  def sink[T](bufferSize: Int): Sink[T, Source[T, NotUsed]] = // ...
  // ...
}
```

Below is sample code for a simple pub-sub channel `busFlow` (similar to the example in the Akka doc):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.NotUsed

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

val (bfSink, bfSource) = MergeHub.source[String](perProducerBufferSize = 32).
  toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[String](bufferSize = 256))(Keep.both).
  run

// Optional: avoid building up backpressure when there is no subscribers
bfSource.runWith(Sink.ignore)

val busFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(bfSink, bfSource)
```

Testing `busFlow`:

```
Source(101 to 103).map(i => s"Batch(A)-$i").
  delay(2.seconds, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure).
  viaMat(busFlow)(Keep.right).
  to(Sink.foreach{ case s: String => println("Consumer(1)-" + s) }).
  run

Source(104 to 105).map(i => s"Batch(B)-$i").
  viaMat(busFlow)(Keep.right).
  to(Sink.foreach{ case s: String => println("Consumer(2)-" + s) }).
  run

// Consumer(2)-Batch(B)-104
// Consumer(2)-Batch(B)-105
// Consumer(1)-Batch(B)-104
// Consumer(1)-Batch(B)-105
// Consumer(1)-Batch(A)-101
// Consumer(1)-Batch(A)-102
// Consumer(2)-Batch(A)-101
// Consumer(1)-Batch(A)-103
// Consumer(2)-Batch(A)-102
// Consumer(2)-Batch(A)-103
```

Serving as a pub-sub channel, the input of `busFlow` is published via `bfSink` to all subscribers while its output streams through `bfSource` all the elements published.  For example:

```
val p1 = Source.tick[Int](0.seconds, 5.seconds, 5).map(_.toString)
p1.runWith(bfSink)

val p2 = Source.tick[Int](2.seconds, 10.seconds, 10).map(_.toString)
p2.runWith(bfSink)

val s1 = bfSource
s1.runForeach(x => println(s"s1 --> $x"))

val s2 = bfSource
s2.runForeach(x => println(s"s2 --> $x"))

// s1 --> 5
// s2 --> 5
// s1 --> 10
// s2 --> 10
// s2 --> 5
// s1 --> 5
// s2 --> 5
// s1 --> 5
// s1 --> 10
// s2 --> 10
// s2 --> 5
// s1 --> 5
// ...
```

Other relevant topics that might be of interest include [`KillSwitch`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#controlling-stream-completion-with-killswitch) for stream completion control and [`PartitionHub`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#using-the-partitionhub) for routing Stream elements from a given producer to a dynamic set of consumers.

Comment: Thanks Leo but this is not useful for what I want to achieve. I'll post an example to what I actually did shortly.

Comment: @Zohar Etzioni, maybe the sample code didn't illustrate the pub-sub functionality clearly enough.  Please see the expanded answer.

Comment: Is there away to map the result of the expression p1.runWith(bfSink) to a future?

Comment: Unfortunately no, `bfSink` is by definition a `Sink[T, NotUsed]`, returning no result from materialization.

Comment: I thought as much. that's a problem because my pub sub bus is a grpc service, so publish needs to return a future. Is there a way around it with broadcasthub? separately is there anything wrong with my solution with source.queue?

Comment: The `busFlow` example is really just a use case of combining MergeHub and BroadcastHub in the simplest form.  Pretty sure more robust `channels` can be composed for other use cases.  As to using Source.queue, it's a good solution as long as it effectively addresses your specific need.  I would generally lean towards an Akka Stream API solution which tends to more readily blend with other provided functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing. Both publishers and subscribers can come and disappear and regardless of when a subscriber joins and when a publisher joins, the subscriber should be able to see all published messages for their subscription (by topic) irrespective of which publishers were active at the time the subscription was made. Comments are welcome.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
   val materializerSettings = ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem)
   implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(materializerSettings)(actorSystem)
   implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

   val (queue, pub) = Source.queue[Int](100, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropHead).toMat(Sink.asPublisher(true))(Keep.both).run()

   val p1 = Source.tick[Int](0.seconds, 5.seconds, 5)

   p1.runForeach(x=> {queue.offer(x)})

   val p2= Source.tick[Int](2.seconds,10.seconds, 10)
   p2.runForeach(x=> queue.offer(x))

   val s1 = Source.fromPublisher(pub)
   s1.runForeach(x=> println(s"s1 =======> ${x}"))

   val s2 = Source.fromPublisher(pub)
   s2.runForeach(x=> println(s"s2 =======> ${x}"))
}
```