# With Akka Stream, how to dynamically duplicate a flow?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm running a live video streaming server. There's an `Array[Byte]` video source. Note that I can't get 2 connections to my video source. I want every client connecting to my server to receive this same stream, with a buffer discarding the old frames.

I tried using a `BroadcastHub` like this :

```scala
  val source =
    Source.fromIterator(() => myVideoStreamingSource.zipWithIndex)

  val runnableGraph =
    source.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 2))(Keep.right)

  runnableGraph.run().to(Sink.foreach { index =>
      println(s"client A reading frame #$index")
  }).run()

  runnableGraph.run().to(Sink.foreach { index =>
      println(s"client B reading frame #$index")
  }).run()
```

I get :

```
client A reading frame #0
client B reading frame #1
client A reading frame #2
client B reading frame #3
```

We see that the main stream is partitioned between the two clients, whereas I'd expect my two client being able to see all the source stream's frames.

Did I miss something, or is there any other solution ?

Comment: Your snippet seems to work fine for me (on both Akka 2.5 & 2.6), with each of the clients receiving all stream elements.

Comment: @LeoC, the reason it worked for you is that you defined the iterator as one that can repeat itself. For example, `Seq(0,1,2,3)`, `List(0,1,2,3)`, or `0.to(3)`

Comment: @tmouron, I've just noticed you were materializing the runnableGraph for BroadcastHub more than once.  It should be materialized only once to return from `BroadcastHub.sink` a single Source for dynamically "broadcasting" to multiple consumers.  Your Iterator-type Source is fine if it's only run once which is the typical use case for BroadcastHub.  For more details, take a look at this [Akka Stream doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub) and maybe this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903332/dynamically-merge-akka-streams).

Comment: @TomerShetah, that doesn't seem to be the main issue.  The Source stream shouldn't have been run more than once to begin with.  Please see my other comments.

Comment: @LeoC, seems like https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Hub.scala#L316 can be materialized many times. Once the sink is materialized, the source that created can be consumed many times. BUT, it consumes it lazily. therefore if you use a real iterator, once consumed you won't get the elements anymore. If you tried the code as is, you had the luck to see both clients printing all ekements. Add a sleep between the two. See https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UeNv12KkT0S1LDWmOeFQ2Q vs https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0tPWR4opSf2OZd851JIPYg

Comment: @TomerShetah, no doubt it can be materialized again to produce another Source.  It just isn't a typical use case as illustrated in the Akka Stream tech doc, especially if you want to "broadcast" the exact original Source.

Comment: Indeed, It works even when materializing the source more than once. The issue was my iterator.

However, I had to change the implementation : when client A connects, it gets the stream from time = t1. One hour later, client B connects. It gets the stream from time = t1 too instead of being live. I want the old frames to be discarded. Also, the application gets slower over time. I ended up using an homemade ring buffer, however I'd like to have a full akka-stream solution, so if you have any other idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the combination of `Iterator` with `BroadcastHub`. I assume you `myVideoStreamingSource` is something like:

```
val myVideoStreamingSource = Iterator("A","B","C","D","E")
```

I'll now quote from [`BroadcastHub.Sink`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/12110822df26fc182a8aab6af5ead90b04e7efe3/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Hub.scala#L329):

> Every new materialization of the [[Sink]] results in a new, independent hub, which materializes to its own [[Source]] for consuming the [[Sink]] of that materialization.

The issue here for you, is that it does not yet consume the data from the iterator.

The thing with iterator, is that once you consumed its data, you won't get back to the beginning again. Add to that the fact that both graphs run in parallel, it looks like it "divides" the elements between the two. But actually that is completely random. For example, if you add a sleep of 1 second between the `Client A` and `Client B`, so the only client that will print will be `A`.

In order to get that work, you need to create a source that is reversible. For example, `Seq`, or `List`. The following will do:

```
val myVideoStreamingSource = Seq("A","B","C","D","E")
val source = Source.fromIterator(() => myVideoStreamingSource.zipWithIndex.iterator)
```

Comment: Indeed, I had an issue because of the iterator. I ended up with `Source.repeat({}).mapAsync(readFrame)` and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tmouron, you can also use [Source.cycle](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.scala#L305)